# IP to host name

Tags: java, ip

I am trying to write code that will return me a domain name if I give it a IP address. Here is what I have done so far;

```
String destination = "173.194.24.144";
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(destination);
String resolvedHost = address.getHostName();
System.out.println("Translated " + destination + " to host name " + resolvedHost);
```

What i get is `Translated 173.194.24.144 to host name 173.194.24.144`

I know for a fact that `173.194.24.144` is an IP address for Google. But with just getting this I tried a little experiment and do a somewhat reverse engineering on the situation. I tried this;

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
System.out.println("Host Name " + addr.getHostName());
System.out.println("Host Address " + addr.getHostAddress());

System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

byte [] add = new byte[]{74, 125, 24, (byte) 105};
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(add);
System.out.println("Host Name " + ip.getHostName());
System.out.println("Host Address " + ip.getHostAddress());
```

The IP I get in the response is used in the byte array, but the full result I get is;

```
Host Name www.google.com
Host Address 74.125.24.105
--------------------------------------------
Host Name de-in-f103.1e100.net
Host Address 74.125.24.105
```

But that just made me more confused as I have got `de-in-f103.1e100.net` instead of `www.google.com`

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Comment: Read the javadoc of the InetAdress methods. They explain what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`de-in-f103.1e100.net` redirects to Google.

I'm guessing that `74.125.24.105` actually leads to `de-in-f103.1e100.net`, which then redirects to Google. In the first one, you created an `InetAddress` pointing to `google.com` with the same ip. You could get to google by tracing the redirects (`tracert` on windows command line).

Comment: Is there a way I can get it to return `www.google.com` rather than `de-in-f103.1e100.net`?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading and doing more investigating I was finally able to answer the question. If I add the IP address and domain name to the `/etc/hosts` file and run the class again, it will produce the domain name I inserted into the `/etc/hosts` file, instead of the original response.

Comment: How is that a solution? Let me rephrase that question: what kind of business requirement were you trying to solve for which this is a valid maintainable solution? You might as well create your own version of InetAddress which hardcoded returns google.com when you feed it that IP.

Comment: Well I was looking to get returned `Translated 173.194.24.144 to host name www.google.com` but i kept getting `Translated 173.194.24.144 to host name 173.194.24.144`. Yes I will admit it is not ideal but it does answer the question I had